# Javascript onclick event not working with variable reference

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementbyid, selectors-api

I am reading some code and trying to replicate the same at my end step by step.

I am attaching an event to a particular button and onclick it should log a statement.

Following is the code that does not work :-

```
(function(){

var el = function(element){
    if(element.charAt['0'] === '#'){
        return document.querySelector(element);
    }
    return document.querySelectorAll(element);
}

var viewer = el('#viewer');
var clear = el('#clear');

console.log(clear);

 var clearAll = function(){
    console.log('Clearing');
 };

//click event
clear.onclick = clearAll;

})();
```

Above a function is used to get elements.

The below code works

```
document.getElementById('clear').onclick = clearAll;
```

or

```
document.querySelector('#clear').onclick = clearAll;
```

I do not understand why the above code does not work. Please Help.

Comment: A function which sometimes returns an element and sometimes returns a node list is likely to be confusing. I don't recommend doing that.

Answer (score 1):

`"foo".charAt['0']` is `undefined` because `charAt` is a **function** and doesn't have a `0` property.

You need `()` (to call the function), not `[]` (to access properties of the object).

Comment: Ohhhhh...yes that worked...stupid mistake...Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You are using charAt as an array while it is a function.

```
var el = function(element){
    if(element.charAt('0') === '#'){
        return document.querySelector(element);
    }
    return document.querySelectorAll(element);
}
```

See it working https://jsfiddle.net/

Regards,